# field of fractions and being algebraically closed

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

prove that for every field $F$ the field of fractions $F(x)$ is not algebraically closed.

it is a problem which i don't know how to deal with it.

help please.

thank you.

Comment: If $F(x)$ were algebraically closed, it would contain a square root of $x$.  Can you show that no element of $F(x)$ can give $x$ when you square it?

Comment: @AndreasBlass if $(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})^2=x$ then we have $f(x)^2=x g(x)^2$ which is impossible ,because the degree of one side is even and the other's is odd.true?

Comment: @AndreasBlass but i don't know why $F(x)$ must contain $\sqrt x$

Comment: It's a little confusing: the field of fractions... **of the integral domain** $\;F[x]\;$ , right?

Comment: @Timbuc the elements of the field of fractions of $F(x)$ have this form : $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ when $f,g$ are the polynomials over $F$

Comment: I know, @user115608 (and $\;g(x)\neq 0\;$ )...it is just that you passed from "the field $\; F\;$" to the fraction field $\;F(x)\;$ without going through the polynomials ring...and *by definition*, $\;\sqrt x\notin F(x)\;$ as the square root is *not* a rational function in $\;x\;$ .

Comment: @user115608, it is just that it is more usual, or at least I'm more used to, talk of "the field of fractions" referring to some integral domain. You did not mention the inegral domain.

Comment: The last idea (the square root one) is what proves what you want, dosn't it?

Comment: @Timbuc no because i don't know why the square root belongs to $F(x)$

Comment: @user115608, who says it does?! Read my answer, please...and forget the square root for now.

Comment: An algebraically closed field contains square roots of *all* its elements, because, for each $a$ in the field, the polynomial $Y^2-a$ has to have a zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition

$$F(x)=\left\{\;\;\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\;;\;\;f,g\in F[x]\;,\;\;g(x)\neq 0\right\}$$

If we had

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^2=x\iff f(x)^2=xg(x)^2$$

But $\;\deg f(x)^2\;$ is even, whereas $\;\deg (xg(x))\;$ is odd and you're done.

Comment: ok, but why $\sqrt x \in F(x)$?

Comment: Oh my! It is not in there, @user115608 ! Why do you think it is??

Comment: yes and because of this i'm confused.how do u say$(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})^2=x$?

Comment: @user115608, if $\;F(x)\;$ is alg. closed then it **must** contain a roof of the polynomial $\;t^2-x\in F(x)[t]\;$, right? My answer shows it is impossible $\;F(x)\;$ contains such a root.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the polynomial $S(x,y)=y^2-x$ this does not have a root in $K(x)$. By irreducibility criteria and Gauss Lemma.

Comment: This Answer proceeds along similar lines to ideas in a previous comment and answer, so I'd suggest giving at least a full explanation of your justification, "[b]y irreducibility and Gauss Lemma."  To me it seems more natural to use a degree argument, but another point of view would be a wonderful addition.